# Can anyone clarify how much cost it takes for a user to use a function of a smart contract on ethereum blockchain?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity, bitcoin, smartcontracts

Is it even valuable for devoloping Dapps?
Does it take more money(way higher) for a using a smart contract than a normal application?

Answer (score 0):

`Transaction Fee` depends on `Ether Price`, `Gas Used` and `Gas Price`. For example "standard" **ERC20** token transfer:

https://etherscan.io/tx/0xbdcfe0e5d548d707a8b092884509a4182c9bfccaddfef1a7c7b9d4f9d4efe326

*NOTE*: With 5.8 Gwei `Gas Price` and $210.06 `Ether Price` this is a very cheap transaction today.

For more info use [ethgasstation.info](https://ethgasstation.info)

Answer (score 0):

There are alot of factors involved in calculating the cost of a function. e.g. **amount of gas used** and **gas price** etc. If you want to calculate the exact cost of your function executation, you can connect **Metamask** to your SmartContract(Ethereum node). While sending a transaction it will give you all the required information of your transaction including your transaction cost accorfing to the current Ethereum price.